# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on UIPickerView - I need a bit of direction on why

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uipickerview

I get the exc_bad_access error when running my project and trying to change the picker.

The error is occurring on

```
 - (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
             titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
            forComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

Below is my code. From reading the other SO articles I realize I am probably not retaining my variable. I'm new and learning and appreciate the help.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "RootViewController.h"

@class RootViewController;

@interface AddConditionViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate> {

    IBOutlet UITextField *txtConditionDetail;
    IBOutlet UITextField *txtConditionArea;
    IBOutlet UIPickerView *conditionNamesPicker;
    NSMutableArray *names;
    NSMutableArray *conditionDefs;
    RootViewController *rvc;
    NSString *conditionName;

}

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *conditionNamesPicker;
@property (nonatomic,assign) RootViewController *rvc;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *conditionName;
@property (nonatomic,assign) NSMutableArray *names;
@property (nonatomic,assign) NSMutableArray *conditionDefs;

@end


#import "AddConditionViewController.h"
#import "ConditionsAppDelegate.h"
#import "Condition.h"
#import "ConditionDef.h"
#import "Formula.h"

@implementation AddConditionViewController

@synthesize rvc, conditionNamesPicker, names, conditionDefs, conditionName;

/*
// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically.
- (void)loadView {
}
*/


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"Add Condition";

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                              initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel 
                                               target:self action:@selector(cancel_Clicked:)] autorelease];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                               initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSave 
                                               target:self action:@selector(save_Clicked:)] autorelease];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];

    ConditionsAppDelegate *appDelegate = (ConditionsAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    conditionDefs = appDelegate.getConditionDefs;

    self.names = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[conditionDefs count]];

    for (ConditionDef *def in conditionDefs) {
        NSString *condition_name = def.condition_name;

        if (!condition_name) {
            condition_name = @"<Unknown Account>";
        }
        [names addObject:condition_name];
    }

    self.conditionNamesPicker.dataSource = self;
    self.conditionNamesPicker.delegate = self;

    NSLog(@"LINE 48");

 }


- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    //Set the textboxes to empty string.
    txtConditionArea.text = @"";
    txtConditionDetail.text = @"";

    //Make the Category name textfield to be the first responder.
    [txtConditionArea becomeFirstResponder];

    NSLog(@"LINE 63");

}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning]; // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview
    // Release anything that's not essential, such as cached data
}

// The number of columns of data
- (int)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

// The number of rows of data
- (int)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSLog(@" LINE 87 - COUNT OF CONDITION DEFS TO SHOW = %i", names.count);

    [conditionNamesPicker setDataSource:self];

    return [names count];

}

// The data to return for the row and component (column) that's being passed in
- (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
            titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
           forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
//    NSLog(@"LINE 94 - here is the bug: conditionDefs[row] %@", names[row]);
    return names[row];
}

// Catpure the picker view selection
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    // This method is triggered whenever the user makes a change to the picker selection.
    // The parameter named row and component represents what was selected.

    conditionName = names[row];

}


- (void) save_Clicked:(id)sender {

    ConditionsAppDelegate *appDelegate = (ConditionsAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    //Create a Condition Object.
    Condition *c = [[Condition alloc] init];

    NSInteger newId = c.getNextConditionId;

    Condition *cond = [[Condition alloc] initWithPrimaryKey:newId];

    cond.condition_area = txtConditionArea.text;
    cond.condition_detail = txtConditionDetail.text;
    cond.condition_name = conditionName;

    //Add the object
//    [appDelegate addCondition:cond];
    [appDelegate populateFromDatabase];

    // ADD TO THE ARRAY: 
//    [cvc.categories addObject:cond];
//    [cvc.Conditions addObject:cond];

    rvc.Conditions = [appDelegate activeConditions];

    // UPDATE THE TABLEVIEW
    [rvc.tableView reloadData];

    // release
    [cond release];
    [c release];

    //Dismiss the controller.
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: nil];
}

- (void) cancel_Clicked:(id)sender {

    //Dismiss the controller.
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: nil];
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField {
    NSLog(@"LINE 159");

    [theTextField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [txtConditionArea release];
    [txtConditionDetail release];
    [conditionNamesPicker release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Comment: You need to provide more information on how exactly your crash is happening. Is is crashing directly while you run or is it crashing after some user action? Also include the crash error that you got in question.

Comment: Ok thanks and I added this data to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change the property `assign` to`retain` for names property. And other array or those object inheriting from`NSObject`. It is an object and you are keeping it as assign property. Use assign only for primitive data type. Try this and let me know.

Comment: This did it! After changing it to retain, it worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the data source of PickerView in one the DataSource methods. This is not valid. Remove the below line

```
[conditionNamesPicker setDataSource:self];
```

from function:

```
numberOfRowsInComponent:
```

You are setting it again.

Comment: I removed that line but get the same error message. I updated my original post with more data.

Comment: Are you not using ARC?

Comment: Not that I know of. Not familiar with that.

Comment: Do one thing remove the names object from synthesize and use self.names everywhere instead of names

Comment: I tried that and it gave same error. Also if I remove names from synthesize I get a different error "Autosynthesized property 'names' will use synthesized instance variable '_names', not existing instance variable 'names'. I added the header file above in case that helps.

Comment: I think you are using an older version of XCode. But this should not be an issue.